# QGIS/GDAL Georeference image by CRS and corner coordinates

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, jpeg-2000

I have several images in JP2 format, but for whatever reason the 'geo-information' is in a different file in a bit strange format.
It is the CRS (4326) and the Lat-Long coordinates of the pixels in the corners of the images (UL, UR, LL, LR).

Is there a way to automatically (or manually) convert them into GeoTiff with a correct Geotiff-header, using QGis or GDal?

I also have Matlab and IDL (without ENVI) available.

Comment: What about `gdal_translate -a_ullr`?

Comment: @AndreJ: Oh, totally missed that switch, I'll try it again, in combination with the a_srs switch, thanks!